# In pandas, how to group row together if any value in the columns (or subset of columns) is common?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I would like to group the row together based on the common value in any column.

I have the table that look like this

| index | email | phone | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc@gmail.com | 123456 | 1 |
| 2 | def@gmail.com | NaN | 2 |
| 3 | NaN | 123456 | NaN |
| 4 | def@gmail.com | 987654 | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | 1 |

How can I group together index 1,3,5 (because index 1 and 3 have common phone number, and index 1 and 5 have common UserID)

| index | email | phone | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc@gmail.com | 123456 | 1 |
| 3 | NaN | 123456 | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | 1 |

and group together index 2, 4 (because index 2 and 4 have common email)

| index | email | phone | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | def@gmail.com | NaN | 2 |
| 4 | def@gmail.com | 987654 | NaN |

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need two separate dataframes?

Comment: @Vishnudev not really, my actual task is to count the occurance of the row in the same group (ie. 3 for the first group and 2 for the second group and so on.) so if there are ways able to skip seperating the dataframe, then it would be better, I just thought it easier to visualize and easily lead to my main goal.

Comment: The data is just duplicated missing data. If you have control over the source of data, you might wanna fix it there. It would be a lot of pandas jugglery,

Comment: @Vishnudev not really, it is possible that it is the same person (grouping row in the same group), but contacting in in the different way (by phone, by email, etc.) While it would be easier to make the data clean from the start, this is kind of the challenge I received and I think it may be useful to know how to deal with such problems in the future

Answer (score 2):

Since you wish to keep working in the same dataframe, and because there is the possibility in overlap between types of groups, I suggest creating two extra columns with numbered groups:

```
df['email_groups'] = df.groupby(df.email).ngroup()
df['phone_groups'] = df.groupby(df.phone).ngroup()
```

Result:

|  | index | email | phone | UserID | email_groups | phone_groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | abc@gmail.com | 123456 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | def@gmail.com | nan | 2 | 1 | -1 |
| 2 | 3 | nan | 123456 | nan | -1 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | def@gmail.com | 987654 | nan | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | nan | nan | 1 | -1 | -1 |

Note that empty values will be classified with `-1`. You can count the group sizes with, for example, `df['phone_groups'].value_counts()`, and filter by group number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure an elegant pandas-only solution exists. Here we create a couple of helper functions first then apply then to the df. The main idea is to have a dictionary where we keep track of group ids that we assign to tuples `(email,phone,UserID)` based on partial match in any of the fields

First we load the data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""
index   email   phone   UserID
1   abc@gmail.com   123456  1
2   def@gmail.com   NaN 2
3   NaN 123456  NaN
4   def@gmail.com   987654  NaN
5   NaN NaN 1
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Next we define the `partial_match` function and test it

```
def partial_match(key1, key2):
    ''' 
    Return True if any of the elements of key1 and key2 match
    '''
    for f1, f2 in zip(key1, key2):
        if f1 == f2:
            return True
    return False

# a bit of testing
print(partial_match(('abc@gmail.com',123456.0,.0),(np.NaN,123456.0,np.NaN))) # True
print(partial_match(('abc@gmail.com',123456.0,.0),('def@gmail.com', np.NaN, 2.0))) # False
```

Next we define a global dictionary where we would keep group ids and a function to update it, with a bit of testing

```
# global dictionary of group ids
groups = {}

def assign_group(key):
    '''
    Assign a group number to a new key, either existing if there is a partial match
    or a new one. Also return the group number for the key
    '''

    # first element is assigned 0
    if len(groups) == 0:
        groups[key] = 0
        return groups[key]

    # see if we already have a partial match
    for k in groups:
        if partial_match(k,key):
            groups[key] = groups[k]
            return groups[key]

    # no match -- new group
    groups[key] = max(groups.values())+1
    return groups[key]


# a bit of testing
assign_group(('abc@gmail.com',123456.0,.0))
assign_group((np.NaN,123456.0,np.NaN))
assign_group(('def@gmail.com', np.NaN, 2.0))
print(groups)
```

Testing returns

```
{('abc@gmail.com', 123456.0, 0.0): 0, (nan, 123456.0, nan): 0, ('def@gmail.com', nan, 2.0): 1}
```

Now ready for the main act. We apply `assign_group` to each row in turn, recording the result in `df['group_id']`

```
# populate 'groups' with the data from the df, and add the group id to the df
groups = {}
df['group_id'] =df.apply(lambda row:  assign_group((row['email'],row['phone'],row['UserID'])), axis=1)
df
```

and we get this

```
      index  email            phone    UserID    group_id
--  -------  -------------  -------  --------  ----------
 0        1  abc@gmail.com   123456         1           0
 1        2  def@gmail.com      nan         2           1
 2        3  nan             123456       nan           0
 3        4  def@gmail.com   987654       nan           1
 4        5  nan                nan         1           0
```

Now you can group on `group_id` eg:

```
df.groupby('group_id').count()
```

returns

```
    index   email   phone   UserID
group_id                
0   3       1       2       2
1   2       2       1       1
```